# Issue with Apache camel 2.4 version

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

This is an issue when I change the camel version from 1.6 to 2.4.
I wanted to use a method userOriginaLmessage which was not supported in 1.6. Hence I starte using camel 2.4 version. The code is getting compiled. But when I deploy it in Fuse ESB environment I get below error.

Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [camel-route.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError:

Can you please help me on this ? What can be the issue.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any more error message showing up than what you posted? Seems a bit lacking in information :)

There were a ton of changes from 1.6 to 2.4. You should take a look at the Camel 1.x -> 2.x migration guide if you have not done so already:

http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.2/migration/index.html

Comment: <loc-message>Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [camel-route.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/cvs/rxdw/ePrescribing/datastore/camel/RxSureScriptStoreRouteBuilder, method: configure signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function</loc-message>
<java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/cvs/rxdw/ePrescribing/datastore/camel/RxSureScriptStoreRouteBuilder, method: configure signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function

Comment: stack-trace><![CDATA[org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [camel-route.xml]; nested exception is 


Above is the stack trace that I can see in the error log.